# Messy output - c++ ifstream

Tags: c++

Is there anyway of making it read spaces or even outputting it is the exact same way?

```
ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("Data.txt");
    system("cls");
    std::cout << "Wip" << std::endl;

    ifstream myReadFile;
    myReadFile.open("Data.txt");
    std::string output;
    std::getline(myReadFile, output);
    std::cout << output << "\n";
    myReadFile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

sample data;

> Name: jobes lobes
>   Age: 89
>   Address: 9 neuern_st mucgregor brosbane australia

It is only returning the first line
is there any way of making it output all of lines?

Comment: Do you want it to also read the "Name:", "Age:", and "Address:" text as well?

Answer (score 0):

`operator >>` separate input data by `' '`, `'\n'`, etc., like `scanf()`. If you want read a whole line, like `gets()`, you should use `basic_istream<>::getline` or `std::getline`.

```
std::string output;
std::getline(myReadFile, output);
std::cout << output << "\n";
```

or

```
char output[100];
myReadFile.getline(output, sizeof(output) / sizeof(output[0]));
std::cout << output << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

use std::ifstream::getline instead.

```
   myReadFile.getline(output, sizeof(output), '\n');
   std::cout << output << std::endl;
```

the getline member function seperates the input by '\n', so that you can safely append an 'endl' at the end of the output stream.

here is the documentation of getline: [getline doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/)